# If check box is already selected, then quit application

Tags: command, applescript, conditional-statements, dictation

I created a script to be activated by using the dictation command "Enable Sharing" which successfully opens up System preferences/ Sharing/ then it will click the checkbox automatically whether it is enabled or disabled already.

I would like to have two dictation commands, one for enable sharing and one for disable sharing. How can I add a conditional that when I say "Enable Sharing" it will run through the script and if the sharing checkbox is already selected, just quit system preferences instead of clicking that checkbox if it is already selected which actually would deselect that checkbox?

```
activate application "System Preferences"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "Sharing" of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences"
    end tell
end tell
activate application "System Preferences"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click checkbox 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing"
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences"
quit
end tell
```

Comment: Similar question and 2 answers are provided on this site : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39336792/how-do-i-use-applescript-to-get-this-checkmark-clicked). One of the answer tests the value of check box of pref pane 'Sharaing'.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I saw that post earlier but after your comment, I went back and read through it more thoroughly. And I think It may have pointed me in the right direction. Thanks again for the heads-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!!! After trying all sorts of different combinations.. This is the script that actually worked as I needed it to..

```
activate application "System Preferences"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "Sharing" of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences"
    end tell
end tell
activate application "System Preferences"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell checkbox 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing" to if value is 0 then click
        delay 1
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences"
     quit
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I fixed it for you.

```
activate application "System Preferences"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        click button "Sharing" of scroll area 1 of window "System Preferences"
    end tell
end tell
activate application "System Preferences"
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"


        set theCheckbox to checkbox 1 of row 2 of table 1 of scroll area 1 of group 1 of window "Sharing"
        tell theCheckbox
            if false then click theCheckbox
        end tell


    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Preferences"
    quit
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort and trying to help me but I copied that code exactly as it is in your post and ran the script and it did not work.. The results were... whether the checkbox was already selected or not, it did neither select or deselect the checkbox.. I also tried several different variations which did not work either. I will keep trying though and will post my results if I can figure it out. Thanks again